# What to do when question on a Stack Exchange site should/could be on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, questions, moderation

I long found the proposal of Stack Exchange interesting, but risky. Staff members themselves are considering some proposals as [overlaping](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/should-unix-linux-and-ubuntu-be-merged-vote/). But there are also cases when questions asked on some Stack Exchange sites can/should/would be moved to the initial sites.

This question ["Java exception handling: I want to repair errors"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6933/java-exception-handling-i-want-to-repair-errors) was asked today on programmes.stackexchange.com, and was latter copied on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785346/java-exception-handling-i-want-to-repair-errors). What should be the community behaviour on such question?

1. Ask moderators for moving this question and the associated replies to Stack Overflow
2. Close question on Stack Overflow as a duplicate of the question on programmers.stackexchange.com?
3. Make them one unique question, answerable by members of both communities (a kind of magically merged question, or a polyglot question - rising the issues that [polyglot programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172219/is-polyglot-programming-important) typically implies)

In fact, behind this simple question, is also discussed the interest of having two sites that seems to overlap like the best Venn diagram. How far will programmers go without becoming a shadow over Stack Overflow (or reciprocally). Is this overlapping investigated during the beta phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close then delete.

Question migration will not be supported until sites leave beta.

Comment: Why?  What the problem with migration AWAY from a beta site

Comment: And do you have an idea of the way questions will be migrated ?